# Reference suggestion: eigenvalues of tridiagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to ask for a reference on the problem of computing the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of tridiagonal matrices (not necessarily with constant diagonals).

I have seen authors use continued fractions and generating functions. However, I have thus far been unable to really grasp the foundations of this idea. From what I can see, the idea is really to reduce it to a difference equations. Then, perhaps, my request is for a good book on difference equations. 
Moreover, is there any technique which is really of a broad scope; ie applicable to a broad range of problems.

Thank you all in advance,

Gabieel

Comment: A few notes: if the products of the corresponding subdiagonal and superdiagonal elements are positive, you can, through a similarity transformation, always reduce your tridiagonal eigenproblem to a *symmetric* tridiagonal eigenproblem, which is very much well studied. The unsymmetric eigenproblems that do not yield to this treatment are said to be a difficult case for the QR algorithm and related methods.

Comment: See Horn and Johnson: Topics in Matrix Analysis. This book is reference in matrix analysis.

Comment: @Elias Great. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Elias Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1):

I tried looking up this subject on Google and found this article that seems extremely relevant to your problem: [Eigenvalues of Several Tridiagonal Matrices](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/AMEN/2005/040903-7.pdf). This article uses symbolic calculus to compute eigenvalues (which I barely know a thing about; I'm not one who works with linear algebra) of multiple tridiagonal matrices. I believe this one should help you, I've skimmed through it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for numerical computation of the eigenvalues and -vectors, you'll have to look at [*A Divide-and-Conquer Algorithm for the Symmetric Tridiagonal Eigenproblem*](https://doi.org/10.1137/S0895479892241287) by Gu and Eisenstat. It is still considered the gold standard on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

A continuous version of a problem may be the Sturm-Liouville problem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory

Answer (score -1):

I strongly recommend the paper "[Eigenvalue computation in the 20th century](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0377-0427(00)00413-1/)" by Golub & van der Vorst and the references therein.